# Should I rebase master to feature branch?

Tags: git

I have been using merge to merge commits from master branch to my feature branch all the while and then use pull request/merge request to squash and do final commit to master branch.

But now in my new team, they use rebase. I'm new to rebase. What I know is that it's good to rebase feature branch TO master branch for cleaner history and stuff. But how about the other way round? When I'm in development and I want latest changes from master, should I rebase or merge FROM master branch to feature branch?? What is the benefits in this scenario?

[When do you use Git rebase instead of Git merge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804115/when-do-you-use-git-rebase-instead-of-git-merge)

Comment: Git is not an acronym. This is an opinion question and not appropriate for Stackoverflow. Git is a tool, and rebasing and merging are both things you can do with this tool. Neither are "better" than the other. Rebasing has some benefits, like a "cleaner" history, and it's easier to reason about, since merge commits are confusing (merge commits have two parents). Take time to learn Git, learn both merges and rebases. Learn the tools you use, get good at them, don't guess at how they work.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Hmm, I'll wait for a better answer on my scenario. Thanks

Comment: If you want to get better at understanding git: https://learngitbranching.js.org/. If you want to get a better overview over what happens locally learn to use the command `gitk`.

Comment: As for if you should rebase master to your branch? The answer is always no... Rebase copies all commits from the branch which is rebased, and move them all on top of another branch. If you rebase master to another place you basically rewrite the history of master which will end up causing "fun" for your entire team.

Comment: Rebasing your feature branch on top of master gets you all commits of master "into" your branch. You almost never want to do the reverse. Close voters: this question is not seeking recommendations, but asking in which direction a rebase shoul be performed (which is answerable: never rebase master, only rebase onto master)

Comment: I agree with @knittl that the question is easily answerable as written, perhaps with a few grammar tweaks to fix up on/in with onto/into. I'd go a step further and say not only is the question answerable, but whether you merge into your feature branch, or rebase your feature onto master, doesn't even make a difference if you end up using Squash Merge when completing the MR. ;)

Comment: @TTT yeah, isnt it? it's no difference when end up using Squash Merge when completing the MR, right? That's what I thought. haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You usually want to rebase feature *onto* master and not the other way round. Commits in Git are permanent and immutable; they can never be changed after they have been created.

Rebase does not change commits, it creates new commits that look like the existing commits. Once all copies are created, the old commits are "forgotten" by moving the branch. Branches in Git are nothing more than pointers to a single commit.

Since the commits on master are generally agreed-on as being "published work" and "shared", you don't want to forget about them – and usually you can't, because other people have local copies of them: everybody would have to forget that the commits ever existed.

What do your two rebase scenarios look like? First, let's look at the history *before* you rebase:

```
         ,D-E-F            < master
...-A-B-C
         `X-Y-Z            < feature
```

For completeness' sake, let's also visualize how the result of merging those two branches would look like.

Scenario 1: "Accepting a feature". This is equivalent to `git checkout master && git merge feature`

```
         ,D-E-F-M         < master
...-A-B-C      /
         `X-Y-Z           < feature
```

Scenario 2: "Syncing with master". This is equivalent to `git checkout feature && git merge master`

```
         ,D-E-F           < master
...-A-B-C      \
         `X-Y-Z-M         < feature
```

If you later then "accept" your feature, you will end up with the following history:

```
         ,D-E-F---N       < master
...-A-B-C      \ /
         `X-Y-Z-M         < feature
```

Scenario 3: "squash merging" (`git checkout master && git merge --squash feature`)

```
         ,D-E-F-S         < master
...-A-B-C
         `X-Y-Z           < feature
```

You get a new commit `S`, but as you can see, it doesn't record its second parent. It's not a merge commit and you cannot find out that its changes were actually done in branch feature.

---

Now, back to rebasing. Same starting history:

```
         ,D-E-F            < master
...-A-B-C
         `X-Y-Z            < feature
```

Scenario 1: "Syncing with master". This is equivalent to `git rebase master feature` (or `git checkout feature && git rebase master`; or even `git --onto master master feature`)

```
         ,D-E-F            < master
...-A-B-C      \
         \      `X'-Y'-Z'  < feature
          \
           `X-Y-Z
```

Note that commits `X`, `Y`, and `Z` are "forgotten", they are no longer *reachable* through any of the branches or tags. The copied commits (denoted by `'`) however are reachable via the updated branch name.

The branch feature now contains changes from both master and from feature.

Commits `D`, `E`, and `F` (reachable via master) are completely ignored by this operation.

Scenario 2: "Not sure what to call this :)" `git rebase feature master` (or `git checkout master && git rebase feature`; or `git rebase --onto feature feature master`)

```
           ,D-E-F          < (origin/master)
          /
         /      ,D'-E'-F'  < master
...-A-B-C      /
         `X-Y-Z            < feature
```

The (public, shared) commits `D`, `E`, and `F` are no longer reachable via your local branch (but still are via the remote-tracking branch and probably through the local branches in other clones).

But if you look at the feature branch, it does still not contain the changes from master!

**TL;DR: when rebasing, you want to rebase your feature branch *onto* master.** You don't want to rewrite shared history.

Comment: Thanks alot for the explanation. Btw, for squash merge (Scenario 3) , you mention we will not be able to tell its changes were actually done in branch feature.
But same for rebase (scenario 1), when eventually we will still need to do a merge request to send the change to master , right?
Because the final end result is that we want a single feature commit to the master branch and not their details, am I right?

Comment: Btw, after i have done all the rebase/conflict resolve, etc and push to feature branch origin ready to be reviewed/merged for MR. Then next day I come and realize there are again new commits to master, I will need to again rebase. But this time, I will need to FORCE PUSH to origin. Then isn't this rebase method raising alot of risk since it involve FORCE pushing? Why is it still the recommended way?

Comment: @neo I'd favor real merges over squash merges every time. Squash merges are not actually merges. I find it very useful to have the history how a feature was developed step-by-step, but others might disagree. So when rebasing, eventually, you would do a real merge (or a fast-forward; I prefer merges as it allows you to do `git log --first-parent master`).

Comment: @neo yes, rebasing requires force-pushing (because you have to tell the remote to "forget" about the previous commits). Force-pushing is not risky if you understand what it does.

Comment: @neo My preferred way to complete a PR/MR is by using a "semi-linear merge". That is, rebase to keep the feature banch up to date, and then merge with `--no-ff` to force the merge commit. This results in a linear history of feature "bubbles", and IMHO is a nice compromise between cleanliness, and maintaining commit history. Nothing wrong with force pushing your own personal feature branches as long as others know not to base work off of it.